# Data are not shown from the WordPress custom table in html select dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to show you all the customer information from the custom table in the select drop-down element using jQuery and Ajax. I tried 2 types of jQuery code for this.  Doesn't show any error or any result. please check my code and tell me where is the problem.

**jQuery Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_url, 
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {
          action: 'customer_list_show' 
        },
        /*success: function(data) {
           console.log('2eee');
          jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var custlist = jQuery("<option>").val(item.id).text(item.firstname);
            jQuery("#itr_customer").append(custlist);
            console.log('222');
             
          });
        },*/

        success: function(response) {
           console.log('111');
          var data = JSON.parse(response);
          jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
            jQuery('#itr_customer').html('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.firstname + '</option>');
            console.log('222');
          });
        },

        /*error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.error(errorThrown);
        }*/
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      }); 

    });
```

**Php code**

```
public function customer_list_show() {
        global $wpdb; 
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_customer_info");
        //echo wp_send_json($results);
        echo wp_json_encode($results);
        wp_die();  
     }
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger. Walk through your code and determine where it goes wrong.

Comment: @mykaf I tried but i cant find the error as a result. I am asking to find the error.

Comment: What does your developer console show? Does it send the request? Receive a response? Have you put any debugging or logging in your php code?

Comment: @mykaf Doesn't show anything in console. network>Preview and Response showing only 0.

Comment: What about the payload?

Comment: @mykaf I fix my issues. I find out my problem. Thank you